# PDO prepare statement not returning results

Tags: php, pdo

Can someone explain to me why the prepare statement in function1 below returns no results, but the query statement in function2 does return results (12).

```
class Test
{   function function1($db)
    {
        //date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
        $month = "January";  //date('F');
        $day = "9";  //date('j');
        // let's query for died today
        $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM graves WHERE dod_month = ? AND dod_day = ? ORDER BY  dod_year DESC");
        $stm->bindValue(1, $month, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->bindValue(2, $day, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
      // $stm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM graves WHERE dod_month = 'January' AND dod_day = '9' ORDER BY  dod_year DESC");
        $affected_rows = $stm->rowCount();

        $stm->execute();

        var_dump($affected_rows,$month,$day);
    }

function function2($db)
{
        //date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
        //$month = "January";  //date('F');
        //$day = "9";  //date('j');
        // let's query for died today
       // $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM graves WHERE dod_month = ? AND dod_day = ? ORDER BY  dod_year DESC");
       // $stm->bindValue(1, $month, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //$stm->bindValue(2, $day, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM graves WHERE dod_month = 'January' AND dod_day = '9' ORDER BY  dod_year DESC");
        $affected_rows = $stm->rowCount();

        $stm->execute();

        var_dump($affected_rows);
    }        


}
```

results of var_dump are:

int 0

string 'January' (length=7)

string '9' (length=1)

int 12

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first function, the line that would actually execute the statement is executed *after* you get the row count.

Comment: It is executed. `$stm->execute()` Except the OP is requesting the affected rows before the execute statement. So it returns 0.

Comment: Thanks, that's not the first time I've done that... knew it had to be something simple because similar code had worked in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse the order of the statements in the first query as follows:

```
$stm->execute();    
$affected_rows = $stm->rowCount();
```

Comment: Yes that's it... thanks. My experience is that the query statement will return results without issuing the execute and execute is not needed in function2

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

You can simply querty row count by calling `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM graves WHERE dod_month = 'January' AND dod_day = '9' ORDER BY  dod_year DESC`